# Running into grid item text overflow vertically on my sidebar

Tags: css, overflow, css-grid

[image]Running into an issue: I have a total of five grid items, but the problem lies within two items: leftbar & rightbar - the text overflows vertically when I scale the page down. Instead, I would like for the text to remain wthin the two grid items and mold around the brand shown in the middle. I understand that I can use overflow:scroll and it would solve my issue, but that's not a solution I'm looking for. Ideally, I want the the left/rightbars to adjust around the other grid items.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class = "header">
        <a href="#"target="_blank"> Hello, World. </a>
        </div>  
    </header>
    <div class = "container flex"> 
        <nav class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Options</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <main class="logo-center">
            <div class= "logo-center-grid-items">
                <h1></h1>
                <h1></h1>
                <h1></h1>
                <h1></h1>   
            </div> 
        </main>
        <div class="leftbar">
            <h3>the art.</h3><br>
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima nostrum facere eum laborum blanditiis exercitationem doloremque. Veritatis suscipit sunt a earum error illum quam, adipisci, fuga corporis in distinctio molestias!
            </p> <br>
            <div class = "creations-btn">
                 <a href= "#">creations</a>
            </div><br>
        </div> 
        <div class="rightbar">
            <h3>the craft.</h3><br>
            <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Minima nostrum facere eum laborum blanditiis exercitationem doloremque. Veritatis suscipit sunt a earum error illum quam, adipisci, fuga corporis in distinctio molestias!
            </p><br>
            <div class = "order-btn">
                 <a href= "#">order</a>
            </div><br>
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="social-media">
                <a href="#"> <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a> 
                <a href="#"> <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a> 
                <a href="#"> <i class="fab fa-discord"></i></a> 
                <a href="#"> <i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a> 
            </div>  
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My CSS:

```
:root{
    --main-radius: 25px;
    --main-padding: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


.container{
    display: grid;
    height: 100vh;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: auto 35% 35% auto;
    grid-template-areas: 
    "nav nav nav nav"
    "leftbar main main rightbar"
    "leftbar main main rightbar"
    "footer footer footer footer";
    grid-gap: 1.5rem;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 45px;
}


/* grid items (5) */
/* nav (deleted for the sake of unimportance) */

/* logo center */
 .logo-center {
    grid-area: main;
    display: grid;
 }

 .logo-center > div {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr); 
    grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);    
 }

 .logo-center h1 {
     background-attachment: fixed;
 }

/* left sidebar */
.leftbar{
    grid-area: leftbar;  
}

/* right sidebar*/
.rightbar{
    grid-area: rightbar;
}

.rightbar > p{
    margin: 20px;
}

/* footer (deleted for the sake of unimportance)  */
```

I did find one solution that allowed the items to form around the grid like I want, adding inline-table to the parents...

```
display:inline-table;
width: 100%;
```

but ultimately this solution comes with the price of the sidebars digging into the footer.

Comment: It's not 100% clear from your question what you want the result to be, so perhaps you could edit it to add a sketch, or at least provide more details. It would also be very easy for you to [create a snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from your code ... a "snippet" is stack overflow's equivalent of a codepen or a jsfiddle ... it's runnable code embedded in a question.

Comment: @BrettDonald hey thanks for responding. I added one small picture and some more information (In the picture, I have 5 grid items. The problem is that within the leftbar and rightbar grid-items, the <p> and buttons are overflowing. Instead, I want the text to remain inside the grid items and mold around the other items. Hopefully this gives you a better visual. I'll work on creating a snippet now

Comment: deleting .container {height:100vh;} and adding .leftrightbars {min-height:0;} solved the issue